# json object deserialize issue typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

As part of my project, I need to write some model data to JSON object and download it to file.
then I need to load that file and deserialize the JSON to model object. 
That part is not working

demo project 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpg5gx

for repro, click on the export button you will get JSON file downloaded  and try to import the exported file

**expected**

```
{"name":"usa","orgAddress1":"123 broadway","orgAddress2":"2D","city":"new york","system":[{"name":"sap"},{"name":"sap"},{"name":"sap"},{"name":"sap"},{"name":"sap"},{"name":"sap"},{"name":"sap"},{"name":"sap"},{"name":"sap"},{"name":"sap"}]}
```

**actual result:**

```
Partner {0: "{", 1: """, 2: "n", 3: "a"…}
0: "{"
1: """
10: "s"
100: "a"
101: "p"
102: """
103: "}"
104: ","
105: "{"
106: """
107: "n"
108: "a"
109: "m"
11: "a"
110: "e"
```

...................

Comment: A minimal but complete example of the code that reproduces the error should be posted directly on this site in the question.

Comment: @crashmstr I did  create I demo project it's in the question, to  repro it click on the export button and try to import exported file

Comment: There is a *link* to what I guess is some code. But you need to have the code *here*, inline, in the question body. [Part of the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your conversions to the following

```js
let json = fileReader.result.toString();
let obj = JSON.parse(json);
var convert = Object.assign(new Partner(), obj);
```

That should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: oh, I knew its something small! thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `JSON.stringify()` on a string before parsing it.  If you remove your `JSON.stringify()` call, it will work as expected.

```
let object = JSON.parse(fileReader.result as string);
```

Comment: can't do it.. then code not complies ...  Error  Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: I updated the answer to cast to string. ArrayBuffer is only if uploading multiple files